# Transfer of electrophoresis bands to MS

Tags: lab-techniques, gel-electrophoresis, mass-spectrometry

I have a lab question that is confusing me. Just to be clear this is a homework question but I've done some extensive research and can't find what seems to be a "good" answer.

The question is this:
List the steps in order that need to be taken between gel electrophoresis band excision and MS?

The only things I can think of are cleaning the salts out of the sample if salting out was used and removing any detergents that were used like SDS. The question seems to imply that there is a specific order or steps required leading me to think there is something I am missing. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of protocols available on line for Protein identification  by LC-MS from gel bands. Just google for it, also try searching for in-gel digestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the salts, remove the dye, digest the protein, extract the digested peptides from the gel etc.

For details, see [this protocol](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nprot.2006.468).